# How to change the css of the focus UI in list view

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view

[image]I have a list view with default settings. When i mouse over on the column of a list, the column back ground color will change to blue as it is the default settings but the text is not highlighting as bold.

How to make the text as bold when i mouse over the column of a list view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this css selector for 2010:

```
tr.ms-itmhover:hover > td
```

and this for 2013:

```
.ms-itmHoverEnabled:hover > *{
font-weight: bold;
}
```

For selected item (remove `.s4-itm-selected > *,` to only get the effect on hover) use this:

```
.s4-itm-selected > *, .s4-itm-selected:hover > *{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But it is only working for selection but not hover.
What are those >,* will do ?

Comment: The first code block is for hover, the second for selection. The "> *" part is telling the browser to apply the rule to any direct child of the object before the ">"

Comment: It works beautifully when I try it :) What browser do you use for testing it?

Comment: But hover code is not working.I am attaching a screen shot please take a look.

Comment: Sorry I thought you where using 2013, I'll have a second look at it

Comment: Updated hover code for 2010

Comment: Glad to here that :)

Comment: can you post both codes for 2010 and 2013 if possible.